# Reformatting excel tables

Tags: python, vba, excel

I have some excel tables which come from ripping text from pdf files into excel. I need to reformat the tables into tables better suited for sqlite querying in an android app. Here's an example of one of the pages ripped from pdf into excel:

```
320E L, 320E LRR                320E L, 320E LRR with Super Long Reach      320F L  
    with VA Boom                        with Reach Boom 
Stick  2.9 m 9'6"    2.5 m  7'6"    6.28 m  20'6"   2.9 m   9'6"
       mm   ft         mm   ft          mm  ft        m ft
A     8410  27'7"     8070  26'6"   11 290  37'0"   6.49    21'4"
B   10 200  33'6"     9800  32'2"   15 720  51'6"   9.86    32'4"
C     6680  21'11"    6270  20'7"   11 690  38'4"   6.72    22'1"
D     5290  17'4"     4890  16'1"   10 670  35'0"   5.06    16'7"
E     6580  21'7"     6170  20'3"   11 590  38'0"   6.55    21'6"
F      —     —         —      —        —     —        —       —
G   11 520  37'10"  11 180  36'8"   13 590  44'6"   9.37    30'9"
```

Here's a screenshot of how the full page of data ripped from the pdf looks in excel. Sorry, I'm not sure how to get the formatting correct in SO.

[image]

And here's how I would like to reformat it: [image]

This is just one page sample out of hundreds of pages. I'm not sure how I should go about doing this. I'm more familiar with using java, but I have used VBA Macros  before so I am open to using a macro and/or a combination of both. Python would also be a good scripting option. I'm also not sure if something like this is even possible, since there's not a "set in stone" formatting in the original pdf. The tables from the pdf will be pretty dynamic as you can see.

Full pdf rip of the first screenshot:

```
320E L, 320E LRR                320E L, 320E LRR with Super Long Reach      320F L  
        with VA Boom                        with Reach Boom 
    Stick   2.9 m   9'6"    2.5 m   7'6"    6.28 m  20'6"   2.9 m   9'6"
        mm  ft  mm  ft  mm  ft  m   ft
    A     8410  27'7"     8070  26'6"   11 290  37'0"   6.49    21'4"
    B   10 200  33'6"     9800  32'2"   15 720  51'6"   9.86    32'4"
    C     6680  21'11"    6270  20'7"   11 690  38'4"   6.72    22'1"
    D     5290  17'4"     4890  16'1"   10 670  35'0"   5.06    16'7"
    E     6580  21'7"     6170  20'3"   11 590  38'0"   6.55    21'6"
    F   —   —   —   —   —   —   —   —
    G   11 520  37'10"  11 180  36'8"   13 590  44'6"   9.37    30'9"


    323D2 L                     323D2 L 
    with Reach Boom                     with Mass Boom  
Stick   1.9 m   6'3"    2.5 m   8'2"    2.92 m  9'7"    1.9 m   6'3"
    m   ft  m   ft  m   ft  m   ft
A   5.99    19'8"   6.59    21'7"   6.77    22'2"   5.53    18'2"
B   8.98    29'5"   9.44    31'0"   9.86    32'4"   8.46    27'9"
C   5.78    19'0"   6.2 20'4"   6.65    21'10"  5.35    17'7"
D   3.74    12'3"   5.09    16'8"   5.52    18'1"   3.88    12'9"
E   5.51    18'1"   5.99    19'8"   6.47    21'3"   5   16'5"
F   —   —   —   —   —   —   —   —
G   8.94    29'4"   9.38    30'9"   9.58    31'5"   8.56    28'1"
```

Additional screenshot:
[image]

Comment: While SO is not a coding service, I am up for a challenge. Could you possibly upload a sample pdf rip in Excel?

Comment: @SilentRevolution I'm not really sure how to upload an excel file. I uploaded the full worksheet from the first screen shot.

Comment: Is the decimal notation of the stick length always in meters, or can that also be in mm, as is the case with A through G? Do the model and boom header always consist of 2 rows directly above the stick length row? Are there always 4 empty rows between the tables? Are all tables on one sheet, or does the rip produce multiple sheets? Uploading an Excel would have to be done via an off-site file host. But for now I can work with the data you've given me.

Comment: @SilentRevolution It doens't matter the decimal notation for stick length, m or mm is fine. And sometimes the boom header is not included so there will just be model number above stick lengths but if the boom is included it will always use "Boom" except when it says "Super Long Reach". It is even possible that there could be two lines of Model Numbers, followed by a line with Boom description. Each sheet represents the rip from one page so hundreds, maybe even thousands of sheets. The number of empty rows between tables is not constant nor is the width of each table.

Comment: You'd almost start thinking they don't want you to process the data... Based on the page you've uploaded, I've managed to write a loop to extract the data but based on your last comment it is useless on tables where there are not exactly 2 header rows above the "Stick" row. Could you upload a couple more screenshots of random pages?

Comment: @SilentRevolution I added the screenshot of the other rip I have. It doesn't show the variability in the format. They made the pdfs not keeping in mind that in the future we would need all of this information in different formats to show different relationships. If you've got a starting point then I can takeover from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I've got so far.

```
Option Explicit

Sub extractData()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim wsDat As Worksheet
    Dim wbRes As Workbook
    Dim rngRowCell As Range, rngColCell As Range
    Dim strModelAndBoom As String, strBoom As String
    Dim arrModels As Variant, arrTemp As Variant

    ReDim arrModelandBoom(0) As Variant
    ReDim arrResult(1 To 10, 0) As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Set wbRes = Workbooks.Add
    With wbRes.Worksheets
        If .Count > 1 Then
            For i = 2 To .Count
                .Item(i).Delete
            Next i
        End If
        .Item(1).Name = "Results"
        With .Item(1)
            With .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 10))
                .WrapText = True
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .ColumnWidth = 12.5
                .Font.Bold = True
            End With
            .Cells(1, 1) = "Model Number"
            .Cells(1, 2) = "Boom Variations"
            .Cells(1, 2).ColumnWidth = 15
            .Cells(1, 3) = "Stick Length Variations (m)"
            .Cells(1, 4) = "A (m)"
            .Cells(1, 5) = "B (m)"
            .Cells(1, 6) = "C (m)"
            .Cells(1, 7) = "D (m)"
            .Cells(1, 8) = "E (m)"
            .Cells(1, 9) = "F (m)"
            .Cells(1, 10) = "G (m)"
        End With
    End With

    For Each wsDat In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With wsDat
            wsDat.Cells.UnMerge
            For Each rngRowCell In .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
                    If Not rngRowCell.Offset(0, 1) = Empty And rngRowCell.Offset(2, 0) = "Stick" Then
                        For Each rngColCell In .Range(rngRowCell.Offset(0, 1), .Cells(rngRowCell.Row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
                            Select Case rngColCell
                                Case Empty
                                    If Join(Array(rngColCell.End(xlToLeft), rngColCell.End(xlToLeft).Offset(1, 0)), " ") = strModelAndBoom And InStr(rngColCell.Offset(2, 0), "m") > 0 Then
                                        For i = LBound(arrModels) To UBound(arrModels)
                                            If UBound(arrResult, 2) = 0 Then
                                                ReDim arrResult(1 To 10, 1 To 1)
                                            Else
                                                ReDim Preserve arrResult(1 To 10, 1 To UBound(arrResult, 2) + 1)
                                            End If
                                            arrResult(1, UBound(arrResult, 2)) = arrModels(i)
                                            arrResult(2, UBound(arrResult, 2)) = strBoom
                                            arrResult(3, UBound(arrResult, 2)) = Val(rngColCell.Offset(2, 0))
                                            For j = 4 To 10
                                                If rngColCell.Offset(3, 0) = "mm" Then
                                                    If Not rngColCell.Offset(j, 0) = Chr(151) Then
                                                        arrResult(j, UBound(arrResult, 2)) = Val(rngColCell.Offset(j, 0)) / 1000
                                                    End If
                                                ElseIf rngColCell.Offset(3, 0) = "m" Then
                                                    If Not rngColCell.Offset(j, 0) = Chr(151) Then
                                                        arrResult(j, UBound(arrResult, 2)) = Val(rngColCell.Offset(j, 0))
                                                    End If
                                                End If
                                            Next j
                                        Next i
                                    End If
                                Case Else
                                    strModelAndBoom = Join(Array(rngColCell, rngColCell.Offset(1, 0)), " ")
                                    arrTemp = Split(strModelAndBoom, "with")
                                    arrModels = Split(arrTemp(0), ", ")
                                    strBoom = Trim(arrTemp(1))
                                    If InStr(1, strBoom, "Boom", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                                        strBoom = Trim(Left(strBoom, InStr(1, strBoom, "Boom", vbTextCompare) - 1))
                                    End If
                                    For i = LBound(arrModels) To UBound(arrModels)
                                        If UBound(arrResult, 2) = 0 Then
                                            ReDim arrResult(1 To 10, 1 To 1)
                                        Else
                                            ReDim Preserve arrResult(1 To 10, 1 To UBound(arrResult, 2) + 1)
                                        End If
                                        arrResult(1, UBound(arrResult, 2)) = arrModels(i)
                                        arrResult(2, UBound(arrResult, 2)) = strBoom
                                        arrResult(3, UBound(arrResult, 2)) = Val(rngColCell.Offset(2, 0))
                                        For j = 4 To 10
                                            If rngColCell.Offset(3, 0) = "mm" Then
                                                If Not rngColCell.Offset(j, 0) = Chr(151) Then
                                                    arrResult(j, UBound(arrResult, 2)) = Val(rngColCell.Offset(j, 0)) / 1000
                                                End If
                                            ElseIf rngColCell.Offset(3, 0) = "m" Then
                                                If Not rngColCell.Offset(j, 0) = Chr(151) Then
                                                    arrResult(j, UBound(arrResult, 2)) = Val(rngColCell.Offset(j, 0))
                                                End If
                                            End If
                                        Next j
                                    Next i
                            End Select
                        Next rngColCell
                    End If
            Next rngRowCell
        End With
    Next wsDat

    With wbRes.Worksheets(1).Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(arrResult, 2), UBound(arrResult, 1))
        .Value = Application.Transpose(arrResult)
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    With wbRes
        With .Worksheets(1).Sort
            With .SortFields
                .Clear
                .Add Key:=wbRes.Worksheets(1).Range(wbRes.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1), wbRes.Worksheets(1).Cells(wbRes.Worksheets(1).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                .Add Key:=wbRes.Worksheets(1).Range(wbRes.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 2), wbRes.Worksheets(1).Cells(wbRes.Worksheets(1).Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                .Add Key:=wbRes.Worksheets(1).Range(wbRes.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 3), wbRes.Worksheets(1).Cells(wbRes.Worksheets(1).Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            End With
            .SetRange wbRes.Worksheets(1).UsedRange
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
        .SaveAs Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Results " & Format(Now, "dd-MM-yy HHmmss"), 51
    End With
    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .Workbooks.Open (.ThisWorkbook.FullName)
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you I appreciate it! I'll let you know if I ever succeed haha